# Disassembled function parameter (unsigned __int8)haystack[19] << 8)

Tags: c++, disassembly

I try to understand what IDA is trying to do with this line. I am learning decompilation. I make some progress by myself but i am stuck. I cannot figure this out at all.

```
sub_1ED08(((unsigned __int8)haystack[19] << 8) | (unsigned __int8)haystack[20]);
```

haystack[19] is char "1" and haystack[20] is letter U.

Further in decompilation i have variable returned by this function (which only stores the function parameter as number.

```
if ( v142 == 12378 )
```

12378 is a function argument in this question. How is this translated?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by myself.

1 - Hex from ASCII table = 0x31
U - Hex from ASCII table = 0x55

0x3155 = 12629